# Changing app drawer wallpaper in Jelly Bean?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, app-drawer

I have Galaxy Nexus running Jelly Bean. Is it possible to change the background color or set a wallpaper for the apps drawer? Right now there is just a solid black background color. It's really bleak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the free [GO Launcher Ex](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex) installed, you can install [Go Launcher Jelly Beans Theme](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex.theme.gs3jbeanad), also free, and fully personalize your backgrounds.

> Ultra clean, sharp APP DRAWER with FREE REPLACEABLE backgrounds
>
> - To change App Drawer background:
>
>   Press Menu > Pref > Visual settings > Backgrounds > App Drawer Background > GO Theme background

[image: Background Example]

Comment: Is it possible (to change drawer background) using the stock launcher? I've searched a lot, but couldn't find an answer =(